# Jquery use name selector for a specific wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following selector:

```
$('#details:input[name=addr]').remove();
```

I'm trying to retrieve all the input fields with `addr` set in the `name` field, from the `#details` div.

However the field is not removed. The selector returns an Object entity but the removal does not happen. What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

`$("#details input[name=addr]").remove()`

Comment: Hi! It doesn't work as expected. It removes the `input[name=addr]` but not the ones inside `#details`

Comment: @TGM just tried in jsfiddle, which worked. Do you have examples to show the case which won't work?

Comment: I tried the code on jsfiddle too and it works. however in my application the script removes some outer div inputs (maybe because it is a much complicated structure than here). I'll keep working on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
    $("#details input[name=addr]").remove();
```